# NetBeans and OpenOffice open plugin

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, plugins, libreoffice

I use NetBeans 8.0 and trying to install open office extension to develope plugin for LibreOffice
I take plugin from this url:
http://people.apache.org/~cmarcum/devtools/

But the only version i can install is 3.0.0 alfa
all other give that error https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuwB4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a plugin for Netbeans 7.x. Try the [plugin v. 4.0.6](http://people.apache.org/~jsc/aoo_plugin/org-openoffice-extensions-4.0.6.nbm) instead provided by Jürgen Schmidt. It [works with NetBeans 8.0 and Apache OpenOffice 4.1.x](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/OpenOffice_NetBeans_Integration#NetBeans_8.0_and_Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.x) (as well as LibreOffice).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem,

OS: OSX 10.8.5

NetBeans: 8

OpenOffice API Plugin: 4.0.5 alpha

[image]